# Gaomon M106K not detected by Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, graphics, lts, design

I just connected this tablet to the pc but `lsusb` doesn't detect the device. I know it works because I tested it in Windows.
This is the script that I've used to install the drivers:

`sudo wget https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/releases/download/v10/digimend-dkms_10_all.deb; sudo dpkg -i ./digimend-dkms_10_all.deb`

This installation seemed to be ok but, the gaomon is still not working.

I've also tried [this method](https://osu.ppy.sh/community/forums/topics/1122479) but with the same results. In fact, using this method the installation process have some errors.

I tryed also to update the kernel from 5.8 to 5.11 but I didn't work neither.

Any clues? I'm anoyed because some people says that this gaomon works out of the box in ubuntu 20.04. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me it's the following.

1. Connect the tablet via usb.
2. Enter in the wacom configuration (just write tablet in the search engine of ubuntu and open the properties). In my case it says that there isn't a tablet detected.
3. With this properties menu opened just unplug and plug the tablet ---> Magically the tablet started to work.

Sometimes it stops working, so I have to do the same process.